# Updating new RSS feeds in android through Service

Tags: java, android, rss, android-service, rss-reader

I am working on a small project where I want to insert RSS feeds into Database all this will be performed in background service, How can I keep looking for new RSS feeds through the service and insert that in database?

Comment: The Service can act independently until you tell it to stop. To add new items, you bind the Activity and service so that they can communicate. The seervice can manage it from there. Just pass back and forth the relavent data as needed. You can also use set values in a class tha the service picks up when looking for new.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do , first refer alarm service .
here I set some code stuff regarding that.

> Setting Alarm manager let say for every 30 sec. that continuously call your web service that fetch your RSS data from any url.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardScreen.this, xxx.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardScreen.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Inside your xxx class , use asyncTask that call your web service and save that RSS data in to database inside onPostExecute() .apply this and let me know if any query .accept if it is working in your case.